# R - Handle long labels in plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have the following function with `ggplot2` plot. One feature of the function is the `str_wrap` function call to handle the very long labels I have.

```
PlotResponseRate <- function(EntryData)
{
  PlotData <- as.data.frame(apply(X = EntryData, MARGIN = 2,
                                           function(x) round(length(which(!is.na(x)))/length(x)*100)))
  colnames(PlotData) <- "TheData"      
  PlotData$TheLabel <- factor(str_wrap(colnames(EntryData), width = 30),
                                     levels = unique(str_wrap(colnames(EntryData), width = 30)))

  Graphe <- ggplot(data = PlotData, aes(x = TheLabel, y = TheData)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "red", width = 0.8) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "Response rate") 
  }
```

It works fine in the "ordinary" R environnement and I want to use it with `plotly`. Therefore, I add the following line of code :

```
PlotData$TheLabel <- gsub(pattern = "\n", replacement = "\n<br>", PlotData$TheLabel)
```

It seems working but there is still a problem : the space in the left of the plot is too wide (I'm not sure but it looks like it is the same space that the long label would do).

How to get around this behavior ?

Here is a simple example :

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

a <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1)
b <- c(2, 1, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, 1)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

colnames(df) <- c("This Is A Long Answer To A Long Question Label For The First Question",
                  "This Is A Long Answer To A Long Question Label For The Second Question")

TheGgplot2Plot <- PlotResponseRate(df)

ThePlotlyPlot <- ggplotly(TheGgplot2Plot)
print(ThePlotlyPlot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plotly_build()` to adjust the margins.

> This generic function creates the list object sent to plotly.js for
>   rendering. Using this function can be useful for overriding defaults
>   provided by ggplotly/plot_ly or for debugging rendering errors.

Use `plotly_build` to generate the list object:

```
ThePlotlyPlot <- plotly_build(TheGgplot2Plot)
```

View the structure:

```
str(ThePlotlyPlot)

..$ layout  :List of 13
  .. ..$ margin       :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ t: num 57.7
  .. .. ..$ r: num 7.31
  .. .. ..$ b: num 54.1
  .. .. ..$ l: num 481
```

Adjust the margins:

```
ThePlotlyPlot$x$layout$margin$l <- 100
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works in R but I have an error in Shiny `output$TheResponseRate <- renderPlotly({
MyPlot <- PlotResponseRate (EntryData = df)
MyPlot <- plotly_build(MyPlot)
MyPlot $x$layout$margin$l <- 180
})`

Comment: The message is "Error in UseMethod: no method for `ggplotly` applicable to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".