# R Shiny - Error "no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class ”c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I have the following simplified example of a Shiny app using plotly graphic.

```
# Function, library, data
PlotResponseRate <- function(EntryData)
{
  PlotData <- as.data.frame(apply(X = EntryData, MARGIN = 2,
                                  function(x) round(length(which(!is.na(x)))/length(x)*100)))
  colnames(PlotData) <- "TheData"
  PlotData$TheLabel <- factor(str_wrap(colnames(EntryData), width = 30),
                              levels = unique(str_wrap(colnames(EntryData), width = 30)))
  PlotData$TheLabel <- gsub(pattern = "\n", replacement = "<br>", PlotData$TheLabel)


  Graphe <- ggplot(data = PlotData, aes(x = TheLabel, y = TheData)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "red", width = 0.8) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "Response rate")
}

library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

a <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1)
b <- c(2, 1, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, 1)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

colnames(df) <- c("This Is A Long Answer To A Long Question Label For The First Question",
                  "This Is A Long Answer To A Long Question Label For The Second Question")

# The Shiny app 
Interface <- 
{
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput(inputId = "Num",
                label = "Choose the questions",
                value = c(1:2), min = 1, max = 2, step = 1),
    plotlyOutput("Myplot")
    )
}

Serveur <- function(input, output)
{
  output$Myplot <- renderPlotly({
    Plot1 <- PlotResponseRate(EntryData = df[c(input$Num[1]:input$Num[2])])
    ggplotly(Plot1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = Interface, server = Serveur)
```

The main feature I want is modifying the structure of the plot. Therefore, I add this line of code in `renderPlotly` after the conversion in a `plotly` graphic.

```
ggplotly(Plot1)
Plot1$x$layout$margin$l <- 180
```

Or when I add this line, I have an error "no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class ”c('double', 'numeric')" and despite efforts I cannot debug. Any idea ?

I precise that it works fine in R command line :
[Handle long labels in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044915/r-handle-long-labels-in-plotly)

Comment: please post code that produces the error, this code works fine for me

Comment: The code doesn't work when you add `Plot1$x$layout$margin$l <- 180` just after `ggplotly(Plot1)`.

Comment: that's because renderPlotly needs an object generated by ggplotly which is what is the result of the code (the last evaluation of the expression is the return value of that expression), while if you add that instruction after, the result of the whole expression is 180 which can't be rendered as a plotly plot, because it's a number. Add it before the call to ggplotly

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044915/r-handle-long-labels-in-plotly?noredirect=1&lq=1. `plotly_build()` is used in place of `ggplolty()`, then you edit the list of the plotly object. Then call plotly object in renderPlotly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments above, the correct code is the following.

```
Serveur <- function(input, output)
{
  output$Myplot <- renderPlotly({
    Plot1 <- PlotResponseRate(EntryData = df[c(input$Num[1]:input$Num[2])])
    Plot1 <- plotly_build(Plot1)
    Plot1$x$layout$margin$l <- 180
    Plot1 <- ggplotly(Plot1)
  })
}
```